# conf.lua not being read (Lua/LOVE 0.8.0)

Tags: lua, config, resolution, love2d

I need a higher resolution for my program to run. For some reason I cannot discern alone, LOVE is not applying (or finding?) `conf.lua`.

My folder architecture is as follows:

```
basefolder/
basefolder/main.lua
basefolder/conf.lua
basefolder/Resources/
```

My `conf.lua` file reads:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.window.width = 1280
    t.window.height = 720
end
```

Is it something with my code, or with how my directory is set up?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.screen.width = 1280
    t.screen.height = 720
end
```

There is no `t.window` field in version 0.8.0, `t.screen` was renamed to `t.window` in version 0.9.0.

See the [Love2D documentation on configuration files](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files).